CKKS Encryption key, decryption key and evaluation key sizes
I am using CKKS to securely compute one function. I am using Pyfhel library with the below parameters for the experiment:
> HE = Pyfhel(context_params={
>     'scheme': 'CKKS',
>     'n': 2**15,         # Polynomial modulus degree
>     'scale': 2**60,     # Scaling factor
>     'qi_sizes': [60] + [60]*12 + [60]  # Chain of moduli sizes })

I want to find the encryption, decryption, and evaluation key sizes under these parameters. Tried to store the keys by using f.write(HE.to_bytes_public_key()) commands. The resulting key sizes are showing as 7.3 MB, 3.7 MB, and 95.4 MB. Are these values correct? What is the mathematical way of computing the key sizes under these parameters? Any suggestions or links are very much appreciated.

The scheme "CKKS" isn't really one scheme, but instead a family of schemes defined by both

some set of parameters (which you include, though in an unclear format) used to instantiate the scheme, as well as

some set of (inequivalent) sub-routines, making up the scheme.


At a minimum, iirc CKKS is compatible with both "gadget-based" and "auxiliary-prime-based" key-switching keys. These have different sizes. Often the later are used, but this is not exclusively done, so the answer your question would depend on whichever implementation choice Pyfhel used.
This is to say that if you pin down exactly what set of sub-routines are used, you could give a mathematical formula for the key sizes. But it is probably easiest to just

generate the keys (as you do) and measure their size, while

ensuring the evaluation keys are actually evaluation keys, e.g. may be used to homomorphically evaluate things in the way you want (or in other terms, are functionally correct).


